# Calling PHP built-in function from within a class

Tags: php, php-parse-error

Please, what is wrong with the following code? And what is the correct way to do it?

```
class SomeClass {
    var $someVar = trim('some value');
}
```

The error I get:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
>   unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
>   in /tmp/testik.php on line 3

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot run a function there. Only constant values are allowed as [initialization values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to object properties. If you need the `trim` function to initialize $someVar, run it in the constructor:

```
class SomeClass {
  var $someVar;

  function __construct() {
    $this->someVar = trim('some value');
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast :) thank you man! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set class variables with function results in PHP. The assigned value has to be a constant string or number. The type of assignment you're doing has to be done via a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class SomeClass {
   $someVar = "";

   public __construct() {
       $this->someVar = trim('some value');
   }
}
```

I believe the problem is that you cannot call functions when you are declaring the member variables like that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize class properties with non-constants.  See e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php.